# Error defining Enum in class: TypeError: 'module' object is not callable

Tags: python, python-2.7, enums, houdini

I have a Python package containing a module:

> myPackage
>
> |----> myModule

where I want to define an enum as a static property of the module.  **I'm using the enum34 module for Python 2.7 in Houdini**

```
#myModule.py
from enum import Enum
class DebugStates(Enum):
    release = 1
    debug = 2
```

In another Python file i then try to import myModule:

```
#OtherPython.py
from myPackage import myModule
```

which is executed when Houdini starts up.  This executes without errors, but when I try and pull up a Python console I get this error and Houdini crashes:

```
"Traceback (most recent call last):
  File \"<stdin>\", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
"
```

Comment: @DyZ: I'm not so sure that applies here. Nowhere in the posted code is a module being called.

Comment: This bug report looks related: https://github.com/pyQode/pyQode/issues/59

Comment: @MartijnPieters But look at the answer with 54 upvotes (the third from the top)?

Comment: @DyZ: but nowhere is there code here that uses `myModule()`. And the class is named `DebugStates`. And there are other reports of this issue with Houdini.

Comment: @DyZ: also, the traceback shows the exception is caused by something read from stdin, not from a module. There is no source code shown for that line. This is does *not* look like a run-of-the-mill case. Provided there really is no other code involved here.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I agree.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Le sigh, I just figured it out, I was changing my module names to protect the innocent in my question.  In real life I was trying to call my module "globals" thinking that the package would act like a namespace boundary.  Apparently not a good idea.

Comment: Yeah, `globals()` is called in plenty of places.